# how to get Extjs Store last insert id?

Tags: extjs

I use rest proxy, I want to know the last 'id' of last insert record, my server side respond as it should be:

before saving:

**id:-1**

**Save:**

```
var values = this.getFrmReciept().getValues();
var record = this.getFrmReciept().getRecord();
var store  = Ext.getStore('recStore');
record.set(values);
record.save();
store.add(record);
alert(record.data.id);//result is '-1'
```

**Respond from server:**

```
{"success":true,"reciept":[{"id":"366","c_id":"57","crdt_auth":"test","typ":"2","clerk_id":"1"}]}
```

After saving I use the same record to get the new '**id**':

```
alert(record.data.id);//result is '-1'
```

How can I get the new 'id' that returned from the server?

Thank you in advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newId = -1;

record.save({
    success: function (rec, op) {
        newId = rec.getId();
        alert(newId);
    }
});
```

---

[Look fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/dko)

Answer (score 1):

The save method is called asynchronously. Therefore you need to pass a callback to the save method that will be called after you receive your response from the server

```
record.save({
    callback : function (record, operation, success) {
        if (success) {
            alert(record.getId()); // should be 366
        }
    }
});
```